# How to get multiple level deep line items using linq in c#?

Tags: c#, linq

**Scenario:**

class **Job** can have multiple **Task**s and each **Task** can have multiple **Charge**s. What I want to do is to get a list of all **Charge**s for any particular job. Below is my code which I am currently using to solve this. But I have a feeling that it is not the best possible solution (because it is using few loops). Can anyone please suggest how can I do it using Linq/Lambda expression? Thanks.

**Code:**

```
//Model Class
public class Job
{
    public int id { set; get; }
    public List<Task> Tasks { set; get; }
}

public class Task
{
    public int id { set; get; }
    public List<TaskCharge> TaskCharges { set; get; }
}

public class TaskCharge
{
    public int id { set; get; }
    public decimal Amount { set; get; }
    public DateTime DateAdded { set; get; }
}
//  Method to GetTransactions
public void GetTransactions()
{
    var transactions = new List<Transaction>();
    if (job.Tasks != null && job.Tasks.Any())
    {
        foreach (var task in job.Tasks)
        {
            if (task.TaskCharges != null && task.TaskCharges.Any())
            {
                foreach (var tc in task.TaskCharges)
                {
                    if (tc.IsAccepted)
                    {
                        transactions.Add(new Transaction
                        {
                            //assign properties like below
                            //Description = tc.Description, 
                            //TransactionAmount = tc.Amount
                            //and so on
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. I am currently trying your suggested solutions and once succeeded, will mark respective answer as **Answer**. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```cs
var tasks = job.Tasks ?? Enumerable.Empty<Task>();
var transactions = tasks
    .Where(t => t.TaskCharges != null)
    .SelectMany(t => t.TaskCharges)
    .Where(tc => tc.IsAccepted)
    .Select(tc => new Transaction(...));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a few ways:

```
transactions.AddRange(from task in job.Tasks
                      where task.TaskCharges != null && task.TaskCharges.Any()
                      from tc in task.TaskCharges
                      where tc.IsAccepted
                      select new Transaction {});


foreach (var task in job.Tasks.Where(task => task.TaskCharges != null && task.TaskCharges.Any())) 
{
    transactions.AddRange(from tc in task.TaskCharges
                          where tc.IsAccepted
                          select new Transaction {});
}
```

> But I have a feeling that it is not the best possible solution (because it is using few loops). Can anyone please suggest how can I do it using Linq/Lambda expression?

You need to understand that in the LINQ way, still few loops will run, also few classes and methods will be generate. It's not more efficient but more nicer and maybe easy to maintain and understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can go this way:

```
var transactions = job.Tasks?
                            .SelectMany(task => task.TaskCharges)
                            .Where(taskCharge => taskCharge.IsAccepted)
                            .Select(taskCharge => new Transaction
                            {
                                //assign properties
                            }).ToList();
```